# Add arrows in vim

Tags: vim

Let's say I have this code :

```
CommitEvent 4
FooEvent 3
BarEvent 5
NoneEvent 12
```

And many other lines like this. Using vim, I want to change it to :

```
CommitEvent => 4,
FooEvent    => 3,
BarEvent    => 5,
NoneEvent   => 12,
```

I tried visual block first to get the arrows but it doesn't work because the spaces are not there.

Has someone got an idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the arrows with a search/replace, `:%s/ / => /`, and then it's just a matter of aligning them. There are lots of plugins out there that help with alignment. I use `Tabular`. With tabular the command is `:Tabularize /=>/`.

Comment: `%s/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 => \2,/` to add the commas with the arrows.

Comment: Or s/ \d\+/ =>&,/

Comment: Indeed, I missed the commas. Sorry about that.